# laravel where Clauses on related eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

Hey why i cant use a where clause with 3 params on related eloquent models??

simple example (i want it for a <=)

```
$user->roles->where('active',1);
```

//is working

```
$user->roles->where('active','=',1);
```

//is not working

Can i use it with 3 params only in:

```
DB::table('users')->where('votes', '=', 100)->get();
```

and not in:

```
$xy->users->where('votes', '=', 100);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$user->roles` is returning a `Collection`, which has a method `where` on it that accepts exactly two parameters:

```
$user->roles->where("key", "value");
```

As seen in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where

If you want to use three, you'll need to return a `Query Builder` instance:

```
$user->roles()->where("key", "operator", "value")->get();
```